# How to write a certain expression as a total derivative?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to write the expression $g'(g'')^2$ as a total derivative, i.e. I would like to find some (analytical) expression, call it $h$, so that $h' = g'(g'')^2$. The expression $h$ can involve $g$ and any of its derivatives, as well as special functions, logarithms, etc.

Disclaimer: I don't know if this is even possible. If it's impossible, a reasonable argument why that's the case would be appreciated.

Thanks so much!

EDIT:
Editing to include the entire expression:
$\frac{1}{8}[2(g')^2g'']'-g'(g'')^2$

I would like to interpret this as the gradient of some potential — if this is impossible I will likely need to find an alternative way to look at the expression.

Comment: Essentially, you're asking if you can integrate $g'(g'')^2;$ that does not appear to be possible (Mathematica can't do it, at least). Do you have any other information? Is this expression part of an ODE? If so, what is that ODE?

Comment: I unfortunately need to write it that way in order to interpret it as an effective energy — there is another part of the expression, but I have already managed to write that as a total derivative.

Comment: I would recommend posting your whole problem here. Posting partial problems is a problem: we can't help with any larger ideas.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the post to include the entire expression — if the second part isn't integrable I may just be out of luck, but I'd appreciate any ideas you might have.

Comment: What was your original expression or equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are after some $h$ such that
\begin{align}
h'&=g'(g'')^2.
\end{align}
Well, $h$ would have to be some function of $x$, $g$, $g'$, and $g''$: $h(x,g,g',g'')$. We can then write the total derivative out using the chain rule
\begin{align}
h'&=\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial h}{\partial g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial h}{\partial g'}\frac{\partial g'}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial h}{\partial g''}\frac{\partial g''}{\partial x}\\
&=\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial h}{\partial g}g'+\frac{\partial h}{\partial g'}g''+\frac{\partial h}{\partial g''}g'''.
\end{align}
Now we can match up the two equations to see if such a function exists.
\begin{align}
h'=g'(g'')^2=\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial h}{\partial g}g'+\frac{\partial h}{\partial g'}g''+\frac{\partial h}{\partial g''}g'''.
\end{align}
Unless $g=ae^x$ or $a$, $g'\neq g''\neq g'''$, so then
\begin{align}
0=\frac{\partial h}{\partial g''}g'''.
\end{align}
One must equal zero, so
\begin{align}
g'''=0 \ \ \ \ \ \text{or} \ \ \ \ \ \frac{\partial h}{\partial g''}=0.
\end{align}
Again if $g$ doesn't satisfy this condition,

Remaining is that
\begin{align}
g'(g'')^2=\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial h}{\partial g}g'+\frac{\partial h}{\partial g'}g''.
\end{align}
Perhaps the last factor will allow us to find $h$?
\begin{align}
g'(g'')^2&=\frac{\partial h}{\partial g'}g''\\
g'g''&=\frac{\partial h}{\partial g'}\\
\frac{1}{2}(g')^2g''+f(x,g)&=h(x,g,g').
\end{align}
$h$ is cannot be a function of $g''$, yet that is the only way for $h'=g'(g'')^2$, the other two terms don't help. So there is no function $h$ such that $h'=g'(g'')^2$ in general. (I didn't check the three cases I eliminated $g=ae^x$, $g=a$, $g'''=0$).

Comment: Thanks so much!